# Twitter gem search only returns tweets from the past week

Tags: ruby, twitter, rubygems, hashtag

I'm trying to get tweets containing a certain hashtag with the Twitter.search("#sometag"), however this only returns tweets from the past 7 days.

Anyone know how I can get at least 20 tweets? I've tried everything from take to count...

Otherwise, anyone know of an simple alternative way of just grabbing some hashtag tweets?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, that is a limitation of the Twitter API itself. [This page](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/search) notes that "the Search API usually only serves tweets from the past week."

In order to retrieve older tweets, you'd likely need to use a different (paid) service, such as Datasift or Gnip, or write your own direct web scraper to access the tweets from Twitter's site directly.